# yii2 отображение ошибок валидации формы

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Задача состоит в том чтоб выводить ошибки валидации в плейсхолдер

стандартный template к примеру такой

```
'template' => '{label} <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}{hint}</div></div>'
```

кто знает, как решить задачу?

Comment: У вас есть шаблон, пробуйте редактировать его, вы можете переопределять его полностью

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать решить задачу с помощью jquery, примерно так:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".put-to-placeholder").each(function(){
    $(this).prevAll("input").attr('placeholder', $(this).text() );
  });
});
```

```css
.put-to-placeholder {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
  <span class="put-to-placeholder">error message 1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="2" class="form-control">
  <span class="put-to-placeholder">error message 2</span>
</div>
```